# How can I set shortcuts for Eclipse run configurations?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, eclipse

I have several Run Configurations in Eclipse stored as Favorites. I'd like to set key shortcuts to execute each of them. For example, I want to assign key F11 to favorite #1, F12 to #2 and Ctrl + F11 to #3, etc.

How should I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following steps-On the main toolbar click on Run
 - Run Configurations...
 - select a run configuration file from DVT Generic and click on Shortcuts Tab.
 You can choose to add a shortcut on the main toolbar and/or an accelerator (for example, ALT+SHIFT+1).

Comment: What is "DVT generic"? I see nothing like it in the run configurations menu.